# XP and Vista on 2 hard drives 1 computer

Tags: windows-xp

I have Windows XP and Vista running on my pc but my computer say I have a corrupt file in windows 32 something I can go to the bios but when I put xp cd in to reboot it will not when I get the screen to say if I want to start Vista or Windows my keyboard stop it will not go up or down but when I'm in bios keyboard work fine. I otherwise can't go in the computer I would like to know if I install Windows 7 will I loose my info and files on my pc I checked everything my computer worked fine with xp and vista. But I moved and my pc was off for a few months now I have this problem please can you help me  Kind Regards Michelle

Comment: You should always backup your files before you upgrade to a new version of Windows, and considering your installation is already corrupt, the chances of the upgrade failing increases.  There are direct upgrade paths from both XP and Vista to Windows which means your personal files are safe.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it won't take keyboard input from windows, it sounds like windows has crashed at that point (the mouse cursor might still be moveable). Least painful is to re-install windows versions as an upgrade. A windows upgrade keeps all personal files and directories.

If you are trying to have a dual boot system (choosing to boot Windows 7 or XP when prompted at bootup), then first install XP (as an upgrade to the existing (?) XP install. Then install the new windows 7 over the Vista. Now it should prompt you to boot 7 or XP at bootup, going to  either drive.

A better solution would be to have a single boot Windows 7 system. You can still have your XP system available as a virtual system within Windows 7 (either with "Windows Virtual PC" or ["VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/overview/index.html)"). This will allow you to run your old XP within a window in Win7. You'll have to copy or re-install your old XP files depending on how you build your virtual XP.

Comment: Note that XP hits end-of-life on April 8, 2014. At that point, you (morally but perhaps legally) must have retired your XP (or at the very least, only run it while disconnected from the network), even from your virtual machines.

Comment: Not exactly @ChrisInEdmonton. The end of life for XP just means that MS will not provide support and security patches. Home users can continue to use XP after that time, but it will become gradually increasingly vulnerable over time. See - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/what-does-end-of-support-mean